# Azure Service Fabric - Confusion around framework

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have 2 questions. When I create a new project using VS2017, I can't use.net Core as Frameworks listed are only for .net f/w. Why is it so?

See below:
[image: Project Creation]

The next screen asks for the template. While choosing a stateful or stateless service, we have a different template for .net core and .net framework categories but both of them mentions .net core in the name
[image: Service Template]

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.Net core MVC libraries are [.NET standard 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) libraries, so you can reference them from any supporting platform.

Including full framework applications and .NET Core applications.
[More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#aspnet-core-targeting-net-framework)

Comment: if the libraries are .net standard 2.0, I assume refactoring code of an existing project should be easier? If refactoring forces us to use .net core, its going to be tough

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, if you choose to target .NET Framework you can still create ASP.NET Core service and use ASP.NET Core features. That's not a problem. The only downside is if you want your application to be multi platform (for example run on Linux) you cannot do that. You need to target .NET Core instead.

Comment: An assumption I made for this that .net core uses Kestrel for self hosting and .net framework does not have a self hosting capability which is why one can still use .net framework for console applications but not for web app

Comment: @TarunBhatt If you don't care about other platforms and you will run your cluster on Windows Server only you can do that. Some console service targeting .NET Framework and Web targeting .NET Core

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I am running it only on Windows but I am still trying to understand why there is no option of creating a project of Asp.net f/w. I am making an assumption and maybe you can throw some light. .Net core has self-hosting capabilities while .net f/w does not